Nest Js transactions using Drizzle ORM
Is there a way to handle database transactions in NestJS similar to how it's done in Spring Boot using annotations?
In Spring Boot, transactions are managed with annotations like this:
@Service
public class PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LikeRepository likeRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void createPost(Post post) {
        postRepository.save(post); 
        likeRepository.like(post); 
}

In this example, transactions are automatically applied to the repository methods.
In contrast, in NestJS with Drizzle ORM, transactions need to be manually managed as follows:
@Post('posts')
async create(
  @GetUser('id') userId: number,
  @Body() createPostDto: CreatePostDto,
  @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
) {
  await db.transaction(async tx => {
    const post = await this.postService.create(userId, createPostDto, tx);
    await this.likeService.like(post, tx);
  });
}

This approach can lead to less flexible code. Is there a method in NestJS or Drizzle ORM to handle transactions in a more streamlined and automatic way similar to Spring Boot's @Transactional annotation?
